# Difference between opening an first time installed app And newly compiled Eclipse Project with SQLite

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, apk

After I compile and run my Android Eclipse Project and display it in the emulator for the first time my menus(from sqlite) is still the same in number, even if I tried to open other apps and go back to the emulator installed app, the # of menus(listview) is the same.

The next time I compile run my project, the menus(from sqlite) **doubles** in # but the same menu content. I don't have any idea why the sqlite database doubles or recreate my list.

How Can i prevent or trap these kind of scenario? Can you give me an algorithm, that could help me control the inserting of data everytime I run my project. Or is it necessary to trap it though the app app user just install it once? Thanks. Your response is greatly appreciated.

```
// looping through All Products and insert each data to sqlite
for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {   

    //individually get each arrays
    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

    //adding each data to sqlite database
    db.addContact(new Menu(id.toString(), name.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Need more info on how your executing your above code.  It sounds like everytime you start the app it doing your inserts.  Your inserts should be a part of you DBHelpers onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner in Andriod, I did not understood that once the application is installed in the phone and used, the sqlite database is just created once, so there is no need to worry if I open my app many times, updating database is another concern. It is worth to take note that android apps keeps running, unless destroyed or gets an error.